# Toon Shading Errors

Tags: shaders, toon-shading

I'm trying to create an outline effect for my seagull, but the outline seems to be glitching. It is creating a weird outline along the outside of the wing. I'm not sure why.[image: The glitch is between the wings and the body.]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post.  Can you [edit] your question to include a picture of your node setup and anything else that might help you get a good answer?

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with Occlusion:

There's a gap between the reversed 'outline' mesh and the natural mesh.

The natural mesh of the body is appearing over the outline of the wing between that outline is digging into the mesh.

I am unsure of how to fix this. You may need to manually add a strip of black between your wing and your body as a part of the natural mesh